# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta' when printing a timedelta64 scalar

Tags: python, numpy

When I print a `numpy.timedelta64` scalar using string formatting I get a TypeError.

```
In [10]: td = np.timedelta64(5410102,'us')

In [12]: td.ndim   # check td is really a scalar
Out[12]: 0

In [13]: print("td: {}".format(td))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-bae2acf5773a> in <module>
----> 1 print("td: {}".format(td))

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'

In [14]: print("td: {!r}".format(td))  # printing using repr() works as expected
td: numpy.timedelta64(5410102,'us')

In [15]: print(td)                     # Just printing also works fine
5410102 microseconds
```

Any ideas what's going on?

**Update:**

The error seems to be in the `numpy.timedelta64.__format__()` function.

```
In [67]: td.__format__("")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-6acc460ea008> in <module>
----> 1 td.__format__("")

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'
```

It just seems a bug to me. A work around is to convert it to string before formatting.

```
In [68]: print("{}".format(str(td)))
5410102 microseconds
```

Comment: Sorry about the earlier answer, I was focused on the TypeError message, so I thought converting you an int would solve the issue.

Comment: @Ethan. It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about datetime.timedelta function [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-timedelta-function/). Anyways, it says that this function return an instance of a Date object.

The error appears because you can't concatenate a string with an object.

In order to solve this problem, you need to concatenate the string with a printable representation of the object using one of the follwing ways:

```
print(str + str(object)) # In this case, turns to the toString() function of the object, if exists (otherwise it returns an error). Converts the text the object shows to a string. In this case, it's possible to use that method on Date instances.

print(str + repr(object) # repr() functions returns a printable representation of the object of their class.
```

By the way, the line `print(object)` works because it turns to the toString() function of the object. Using `print(str + object)` is forbidden because it tries to print a non-concatenative variables which is not possible, as explained.

Comment: Thanks for you help but the error is not related to concatenating objects. It is caused by the `__format__` function. See my edit. Note that, although the error says `datetime.timedelta`, I put in a `numpy.timedelta64` object in the string formatting. Apparently the `__format__` function tries to convert it. Indeed a work around is to first convert it to string before formatting.